# How to extract multiple dataframes from dataframe lists in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following object with a lot of lists and I need to convert all of them in dataframes using R...

```
glimpse(pickle_data)

List of 32
 $ 2020-02-01:List of 11
  ..$ model                     :List of 6
  .. ..$ : num [1:88, 1:100] 0.00487 0.13977 -0.07648 0.18417 -0.1105 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:25, 1:100] -0.186 0.0703 0.1479 0.0321 0.1185 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:100(1d)] 0.0119 0.0457 0.023 0.0295 0.0115 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:25, 1:132] -0.024 0.0756 -0.0724 -0.1112 -0.1974 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:33, 1:132] 0.1904 0.1275 0.0684 0.1707 0.017 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:132(1d)] 0.0434 0.0636 0.0444 0.0329 0.0393 ...
  ..$ X_train                   : num [1:2494, 1:13, 1:88] 0.0676 0.0697 0.0717 0.0753 0.0783 ...
  ..$ X_test                    : num [1:3180, 1:13, 1:88] 0.0676 0.0697 0.0717 0.0753 0.0783 ...
  ..$ df_input                  :            feat__price__mean_22_days  ...  feat__us_area_harvested__slope_66_days
ds                                     ...                                        
2010-01-01                        NaN  ...                                     NaN
2010-01-04                        NaN  ...                                     NaN
2010-01-05                        NaN  ...                                     NaN
2010-01-06                        NaN  ...                                     NaN
2010-01-07                        NaN  ...                                     NaN
...                               ...  ...                                     ...
2022-09-13                   0.699482  ...                                0.157974
2022-09-14                   0.705994  ...                                0.163528
2022-09-15                   0.713729  ...                                0.171177
2022-09-16                   0.722944  ...                                0.176913
2022-09-19                   0.728798  ...                                0.184181

[3317 rows x 88 columns]
  ..$ index_test                :DatetimeIndex(['2010-07-13', '2010-07-14', '2010-07-15', '2010-07-16',
               '2010-07-19', '2010-07-20', '2010-07-21', '2010-07-22',
               '2010-07-23', '2010-07-26',
               ...
               '2022-09-06', '2022-09-07', '2022-09-08', '2022-09-09',
               '2022-09-12', '2022-09-13', '2022-09-14', '2022-09-15',
               '2022-09-16', '2022-09-19'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='ds', length=3180, freq=None)
  ..$ window                    : int 12
  ..$ shift_coeff               : int 4
  ..$ target_frequency          : int 6
  ..$ nb_of_months_to_predict   : int 9
  ..$ spine_params              :List of 3
  .. ..$ month_duration: int 22
  .. ..$ week_duration : int 5
  .. ..$ min_periods   : int 7
  ..$ neural_network_hyperparams:List of 10
  .. ..$ number_of_neurons_first_layer: int 25
  .. ..$ l1_regularization            : int 0
  .. ..$ l2_regularization            : int 0
  .. ..$ decrease_reg_deep_layers     : logi TRUE
  .. ..$ decrease_reg_factor          : int 10
  .. ..$ dropout_rate                 : num 0.1
  .. ..$ use_dropout                  : logi TRUE
  .. ..$ initial_learning_rate        : num 0.000151
  .. ..$ output_layer_cell            : chr "lstm"
  .. ..$ gradient_initialization      : int 42
 $ 2020-03-01:List of 11
  ..$ model                     :List of 6
```

It is possible to extract dataframe for the first list and all of them inside him and so on untill  to the end of this object using R?

Comment: Found in the wild [unpickleR](https://rdrr.io/github/d-sharpe/pickleR/man/unpickle.html), perhaps.

Comment: How was this object created in first place?

Comment: @Chris I can read the pickle file using R, but I don´t know how to extract from all this lists usefull dataframes ....

Comment: @Parfait, this object was created in Python after runned a big monster backtesting model